# Change Excel file pivot source Data across multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have 2 files one a register with Data, the other a report file, which does the reporting, using the data from the other.

I want to move and rename the register file, and have the 50 odd data sources also updated without having to manually edit each one.

Can this be done?

I have seen plenty of VBA with internal changes, but none where I can change the file name it references, and leave the reference cells intact.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Basically the reports file has 3 worksheets, which all reference data on the main Register file, which has 3 sheets in it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you click data >  existing sources does it give you one source file or multiple ones for every pivot or reference?

If you are lucky you should be able to link to the newly created / copied and renamed version of the file.

Comment: Hi,I have checked and i only have existing connections on the Data ribbon. when i go there, there are no connections.

Comment: Oh dear, looks like "existing connections" would only work if you defined the data source as an external local file data source right from the beginning. This might be the way to go for anyone reading this and still in the planning phase.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, turns out, is super easy. Especially since you have only two files.

Open both. Go to the source file and click "save as" and save to the new location with new name. The reporting workbook will automatically update all pivot table sources to the new file.

*Tested on Excel 2016*

Comment: If for some reasons this doesn't work for other users (too many files, or constantly changing filenames, external programs moving or renaming the files): This article describes how to do this with macros or VBA scripts. 'https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2012/04/19/change-data-source-for-all-pivot-tables/'